# Where can I find linux kernel text and LKMs in memory?

Tags: linux, memory-management, linux-kernel, operating-system, integrity

Recently, I want write something to verify the integrity of the (Linux) kernel.

For the Linux kernel, the runtime code is determined by two sources:

1. the decompressed kernel image
2. a set of loadable kernel modules(LKMs)

I'm curious about where can I find the kernel image and Loadable Kernel LKMs in kernel memory？
With these information, I can compare the kernel image and LKMs to those which stored in a trusted store.

Comment: I don't understand. What is LKM?
If you search Linux kernel source, look at www.kernel.org

Comment: LKM stand for Loadable Kernel Module i think, i found a HowTo page that has a lot of information about this topic: http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/html_single/Module-HOWTO/

Comment: Please elaborate your question furthermore!
What do you mean by Kernel Text? is it Source code you need?

Comment: Sorry, by "the kernel text" I mean the vmlinuz, which is the kernel executable; and LKM stand for "Loadable Kernel Module".

Answer (score 2):

Linux has a virtual memory system. You can't find the Linux kernel or LKM's in the memory space of your application. You can't even find other applications in your memory space.

Comment: There is `/proc/kcore` though.

Comment: Thanks, @MSalters, I think you mean the process isolation. What I want to know is whether it's possible to locate the kernel image and LKMs in kernel memory? I think during the startup process, the kernel image are loaded to a fixed(?) position. And all LKMs are linked with a linked list, you can find all of them if you have access to one of them. I'm not sure but I'll try to find some docs.

Comment: There's `/dev/kmem` too I believe. What are you trying to do?